# Redirecting images to php script with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to incorporate Adaptive images - http://www.adaptive-images.com/ into my website.

Github account - https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images

Ideally the .htaccess should redirect all images to adaptive-images.php and the output should be resized images.

The images aren't loading. I checked the response headers and its returning text/html. It seems like the request is going to index.php file.

Below is the current .htaccess which i am using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside ai-cache
  # to adaptive-images.php

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ai-cache
  RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php

  # Send all files except css, js or image files to index.php

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php

</IfModule>
```

The first part is where I'm trying to make it work

The second part works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `REQUEST_URI` with `THE_REQUEST` that represents original Apache request and it doesn't change after application of other rules unlike `REQUEST_URI`.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside ai-cache
  # to adaptive-images.php

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ai-cache [NC]
  RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php [L]

  # Send all files except css, js or image files to index.php

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(robots\.txt|\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)) [NC]
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks its working now. I have one more question - Since all files direct to index.php and onwards to a router - does the .htaccess need directives like prevent directory listing or prevent access to .htaccess. Should i still need to protect my .htaccess

Comment: Everything is already rewriting to `index.php` so you should be fine. But to be one safer side you can put `Options -Indexes` at the top to disallow directory listing.